# Javascript is it possible to use file.js and script

Tags: javascript, html

nI am trying to use a id3.js file and calling a function inside a script, but it is not working.

This is the part of the html which is inside a PHP file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    function getValue (dir) {
        // var ret = <?php echo getDirs();?>
        var ret = {0: 'dir', 1: dir};
        return ret;
    };
</script>
```

The id3.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.dKeyT').on('click', function () {
        var tag = $(this).attr('tagName');
        alert("click "+tag);
    });

    $('#dir').on('input', function() {
        var inp = $(this).val();
        var n = inp.lastIndexOf('/');

        if (n !== -1) {
            var dir = inp.substring(0, n+1);
            alert(n + " dir: " + dir);

            var files = getValue(dir);
            alert(files);

            for (var file in files) {
                alert(files[file]);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Is it possible to do something like that?

Console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: getValue is not defined
>  https://www.country-radio.eu/id3.js:16
> jQuery 8
>  https://www.country-radio.eu/id3.js:7
> jQuery 13

> `getDirs`should provide a list of dirs, but is currently commented out
>
> > id3.js 7 `$('#dir').on('input', function(){`

> > id.js 13 `alert(n + " dir: " + dir);`

**Edit2**

I tried differend thinks and suddenly I got the error message ret is not defined. So I tried to do a `var ret = [];` in front of the fill of the ret variable. And it works, unbelivable!! Hier my final code of the script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    function getValue(dir){
    var ret = [];
    ret = <?php echo json_encode(getDirs());?>
    return ret;
    };
</script>
```

And also the php function getDirs

```
function getDirs(){
    error_log("GetDirs called");
    $ret = array();
    $ret[] = 'File1';
    $ret[] = 'File2';
    return $ret;
}
```

Thanks for the support!

By the way the call of the php function from JS is only working, if it is between sript tags and not inside a x.js file. `ret = <?php echo json_encode(getDirs());?>`

Comment: What does `getDirs` return? What are the errors that appear in the browser console?

Comment: your id3.js file is being executed before second script tag and trying to access method that is not yet defined. Try to move second script tag higher (before id3.js script tag), so it will be executed before id3.js

Comment: I moved the `getValue(dir)` function before the id3.js is called. Therult are the same `getValue is not defined.` The script and the id3.js file now header section. Could it bee a problem, the call and the function are in different files. But I also tried to put the jquery code from the id3.js file to the script tag. It is also not working.

Comment: "if it is between sript tags and not inside a x.js file" Because a .js file does not get parsed by php....